# Me explicarían como es que se hace el llamado correcto a una función con punteros?

Tags: c++, dev-c++, visual-c++

Soy bastante nueva en c++ como ya he comentado en otros preguntas soy bastante novata, entonces tal vez lo que se le hagá mas fácil a una persona no es igual para mi. Entonces les quería preguntar si podrían decirme ¿Cómo se hace el llamado de forma correcta de estas dos funciones? El problema es que por mas que modifico la llamada a las dos funciones que ven en la función `main`, no logro hacer que no tire error. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?**EL ERROR DICE QUE ESAS FUNCIONES NO TIENEN DEFINIDA LA VARIABLE EQUIPO**, tal vez sea fácil para personas que ya se la saben de todas todas jejeje, pero la verdad no logro entender como llamar correctamente a una función con vector de punteros de parametro.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>//prototipo para utilizar rand y srand
#include <ctime>//prototipo  para utilizar time

using namespace std;

int valor_aleatorio();
void nombreequipos(char *equipos[5],int,int);
void partidos_normal_penales_moneda(char *equipos[5],int,int);

int main()
{
    nombreequipos(*equipos[5]);//error

   partidos_normal_penales_moneda(*equipos[5]);//error

    return 0;
}

int valor_aleatorio(){
    srand (time(0));
    int aleatorio = 0;

    aleatorio = rand() % 1;

    return aleatorio;
}


void nombreequipos(char *equipos[5],equipocasa,equipovisita;)
{
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"---------------------------------------------- --"<<endl;
    cout<<"-------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

    *equipos[5]=
    {
        "[1] - Barcelona",
        "[2] - Liverpool",
        "[3] - juventus",
        "[4] - barcelona",
        "[5] - Madrid",
    };
    for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
    {
        cout<<equipos[i]<<endl;
    }


    cout<<"\nIngrese el equipo numero 1 (CASA) rango(1-12):";
    cin>>equipocasa;

    while(equipocasa <0 || equipocasa >12 )
    {
        cout<<"\n ERROR";
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"\nIngrese el equipo numero 1 (CASA) rango(1-12):";
        cin>>equipocasa;
    }

    cout<<"\nEl primer equipo es :"<<equipos[equipocasa-1]<<endl;
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"\nIngrese el equipo numero 2 (Visita) rango(1-12):";
    cin>>equipovisita;
    while(equipovisita == equipocasa)
    {
        cout<<"\nError no se puede escoger a un mismo equipo"<<endl;

        cout<<"\nIngrese el equipo numero 2 (Visita) rango(1-12):";
        cin>>equipovisita;

    }

    while(equipovisita <0 || equipovisita >5 )
    {
        cout<<"\n ERROR";
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"\nIngrese el equipo numero 2 (Visita) rango(1-12):";
        cin>>equipovisita;
    }

    cout<<"\nEl segundo equipo es :"<<equipos[equipovisita-1]<<endl;
}

void partidos_normal_penales_moneda(char *equipos[5], equipocasa,equipovisita)
{

    int equipo1,equipo2;

//    system ("cls");
    cout<<"------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"------RONDA NORMAL------"<<endl;
    cout<<"------------------------"<<endl;

cout<<"\n:::: RONDA DE IDA ::::";
char opcion;
 do{
    int acumulador1 =0 , acumulador2 =0;

    for( int i = 1; i<= 2; i++){

    cout<<"PRIMERA VUELTA"<<endl;

    cout<<"Ingrese marcador para equipo"<<equipos[equipocasa-1]<<"para la ronda :";
    cin>>equipo1;
    cout<<"Ingrese marcador para equipo"<< equipos[equipovisita-1]<<"para la ronda :";
    cin>>equipo2;

    acumulador1 = acumulador1+equipo1;
    acumulador2 = acumulador2+equipo2;
}


cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 1 es :"<<acumulador1<<endl;
cout<<"El resultado del acumulador 2 es :"<<acumulador2<<endl;

if(acumulador1>acumulador2){
    cout<<"el ganador es EL PRIMER EQUIPO"<<endl;
}
else{
    cout<<"el ganador es EL SEGUNDO EQUIPO"<<endl;

}

        cout<<"QUIERE calcular otra suma (S/N)"<<endl;
        cin>>opcion;

        //Si ingresan por teclado una letra diferente a S,s,N,n
        while(opcion!='S'&&opcion!='s'&&opcion!='N'&&opcion!='n')
        {
            cout<<"Ingrese solo las teclas S o N en mayuscula o minuscula!!!"<<endl;
            cin>>opcion;
        }

    } while((opcion == 'S') || (opcion == 's'));


}
```

Comment: ¿Qué errores obtienes?

Comment: el error me dice que equipos no esta definida pero nose porque

Comment: osea cuando llamo a las dos funciones a la funcion main, nose bien como deberia llamar a una funcion con un vector de punteros, y alli me tira error

Comment: que equipos no esta definida pero nose porque se produce

Answer (score 2):

Esto no hace lo que crees:

```
int main()
{
    nombreequipos(*equipos[5]);
//                 ~~~~~~~ <--- No pasas ninguna variable

   partidos_normal_penales_moneda(*equipos[5]);//error
//                                 ~~~~~~~ <--- No pasas ninguna variable
    return 0;
}
```

Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
int main()
{
    char *equipos[5];                              // Crear variable 'equipos'
    nombreequipos(equipos, 1, 1);                  // Pasar variable 'equipos'
//                         ^  ^ <-- valor para 'equipovisita'
//                          \___ valor para 'equipocasa'
    partidos_normal_penales_moneda(equipos, 1, 1); // Pasar variable 'equipos'
//              valor para 'equipocasa' --> ^  ^ <-- valor para 'equipovisita'

    return 0;
}
```

Por otro lado, tu código tiene otros errores:

```
//        falta el tipo de dato --> v          v <-- falta el tipo de dato
void nombreequipos(char *equipos[5],equipocasa,equipovisita;)
//                                      Este ';' sobra --> ^
//                          falta el tipo de dato --> v          v <-- falta el tipo de dato
void partidos_normal_penales_moneda(char *equipos[5], equipocasa,equipovisita)
```

La formación<sup>1</sup> es de tamaño cinco pero recorres diez posiciones:

```
*equipos[5]=
//       ^ <-- cinco elementos
{
    "[1] - Barcelona",
    "[2] - Liverpool",
    "[3] - juventus",
    "[4] - barcelona",
    "[5] - Madrid",
};
for(int i=0; i<11; i++)
//      ^ ~~~~ ^^ <-- Desde que 'i' es cero mientras sea menor de once, diez pasos!
{
    cout<<equipos[i]<<endl;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: aun asi no me funciona, porque las dos funciones que cree trabajan con un vector y dos variables de tipo int, entonces me dice que faltan argumentos en las funciones del main

Comment: @EstherPorta perdón, no me fijé, deberás pasar los valores adecuados (que no se cuáles son, pero como el código es tuyo deberías poder averiguarlo), corrijo la respuesta.

Comment: waw me ayudaste mucho @PaperBirdMaster me ayudaste mucho pero te molestia explicarme porque en la funcion main imprimiste equipos, 1, 1? no logro entender porque 1,1 en lugar de las dos variables de tipo int que defini en los prototipos

Comment: algo que queria preguntarte es con respecto a el echo de que yo tengo mi vector creado en los parametros entonces dentro de la funcion no necesito crear otra ves el vector simplemente aria mi codigo normal porque ya esta creada en los parametros, pero la pregunta es porque aun asi me tira error el vector dentro de la funcion ? el error dice cannot convert '<brace-enclosed inicializer list>' to 'char' in assignment en  la linea 52 del codigo pero nose porque se produce ni como solucionarlo me explicarias?